# Regex issue with car submodels

Tags: regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm pulling car submodels from the DB and I'm building my regular expression on the fly.

Here is an example of a search string:
EX-L Sedan 4-Door

Here is my regular expression:
preg_match("/LX|EX|EX-L|LX-P|LX-S/Ui", $input_line, $output_array);

For some reason the output is EX and not EX-L as it supposed to be. Can someone explain why?

Comment: @revo is correct; put your longest common-start terms first eg `EX-L` before `EX`, because matching an alternation stops on the first matching pattern in left-to-right order

Comment: @user1029829 Your question seems unresolved/abandoned, please mark one of the answers below as accepted so your question can be laid to rest.  Also, please consider editing your title to something that better describes your regex issue (and doesn't mention _car submodels_ ) -- maybe "Unexpected Regex Alternation Match" or something.  Having a title with relevant key words will draw better attention from search results.  Finally, please add `php` and `regex-alternation` to your list of tags on the question.  Better questions + Better answers = Better SO

Answer (score 2):

Your pattern is unanchored and thus the first alternative that matches a substring makes the regex engine stop processing the whole group. This is a common behavior with NFA regexes.

Also, there are no quantifiers in your pattern, thus the `/U` modifier  is redundant.

So, you can use

```
/EX-L|LX-P|LX-S|LX|EX/i
```

It is a readable form. However, best practice with regexes is to make sure no alternative branch can match at the same location as another. That means you can use

```
/EX(-L)?|LX(-[PS])?/i
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, the reason for this undesired outcome is because the regex engine is happy to have the first alternative and run for the door since your pattern has no anchors (like: `^`, `$`, and some other lesser known ones).  This is the same short-circuiting behavior you'd see in php's `if($x || $y)` conditions; if `$x` is true there is no need to evaluate further.  But enough about that...

I would like to offer some additional logic that I think is relevant to your case/question.

You say your regex is built on the fly, so I am assuming your method goes something like this:

1. A user identifies which substrings/keywords they want to search for.

   `$strings=array('LX','EX','EX-L','LX-P','LX-S');
   // array of substrings in any order`
2. As mentioned earlier, you need longer strings to precede shorter ones with identical starting characters.

   `rsort($strings);
   // sort DESC, longer strings precede shorter strings when leading characters match`
3. Pipe all strings into a single regex pattern with implode().

   `$piped_regex='/\b(?:'.implode('|',$array).')\b/i';
   // word boundaries ensure the string is not part of a larger word; remove if not desired
   // pattern: /\b(?:LX-S|LX-P|LX|EX-L|EX)\b/i`

   While programmatically condensing your similar strings into a concise pattern as Wiktor recommended is possible, it's probably not worth the effort with your on-the-fly patterns.
4. Finally run preg_match() as normal.

   ```
   $input_line='EX-L Sedan 4-Door';
   if(preg_match($piped_regex,$input_line,$output_array)){
       var_export($output_array);
   }
   // output: array(0=>'EX-L')
   ```

I hope stepping out this method is helpful to you and future SO readers.